# Magento 2: Choose color via product image

Tags: magento2, color-swatches

I found the extension for allow choose color via product image.

https://averun.com/magento-color-swatch-for-configurable-products.html

but It for Magento1, my question is how to do it in Magento2, or have any extension to do it in Magento2?

Any help?
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think in Magento 2 by default provides this functionality.

To allow choose color via product image you have to set the "**Use Product Image for Swatch if Possible**" to **Yes** on your color attribute. check the below images.

[image]

[image]

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Thank for your help.